# San Francisco font + SpriteKit

Tags: ios, fonts, sprite-kit

Is it currently possible to use iOS 9's new San Francisco font in SpriteKit's `SKLabelNode`? Apple has explicitly asked us not to instantiate the font by name, but that's the only way `SKLabelNode` provides for selecting fonts.

Answer (score 3):

Get the system font name by the property `fontName` of `UIFont`:

```
let myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:UIFont.systemFontOfSize(45.0).fontName)
```

Print result of the font name:

```
.SFUIDisplay-Regular
```

**EDIT:**

In terms of [WWDC 2015 Video: Introducing the New System Fonts](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=804), page 298 of PDF says **Don’t Access System Font by Name**, e.g.

```
let myFont = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(mySize)
// …later in the code…
let myOtherFont = UIFont.fontWithName(myFont.familyName size:mySize)
```

The better practice (page 299) is to **Do Reuse Font Descriptors**, e.g.

```
let systemFont = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(mySize)
// …later in the code…
let myOtherFont = UIFont.fontWithDescriptor(systemFont.fontDescriptor()
 size:mySize)
```

Please note the code is describing a situation that you need to access a font (`myFont`) that defined earlier. In order to keep consistency for the font in the App, you'd better use `fontDescriptor` which has already been defined rather than accessing a complete *new* font without setting its attributes. Don't get confused.

Comment: As I said: "Apple has explicitly asked us not to instantiate the font by name". The dot (.) in front of the font name indicates that it's private, and shouldn't be used directly.

Comment: @phu I'm afraid the guideline asks us not to hardcode the font name because the name may be changed with the OS update or something. I don't feel any improper to set font with a property of `UIFont`.

Comment: @phu Also where did you find the guideline you said?

Comment: @phu See my updated answer. Is that where you're confused or you need other explanation?

Comment: I'm well aware of font descriptors, but there's no way to use them with `SKLabelNode`.

Comment: @phu I create a font descriptor and apply it to both `SKLabelNode` and `UILabel`. No luck only `UILabel` will take effect. It seems that to access a `UIFont` with `fontName` won't contain its attributes in SpriteKit.

Answer (score 0):

This is working well for me (in iOS 14.5):

```swift
SKLabelNode(
  attributedText: NSAttributedString(
    string: "My text",
    attributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .bold)]
  )
)
```

Note that you can also choose from among all the different system-font's weights.